Seeking references on second-order optimality conditions in $H^1(Ω)$ space
I am currently working on optimal control problems where the control function belongs to the Sobolev space $ H^1(\Omega) $ and the objective functional is of the type $ J(u,y)=\int_\Omega L(x,y)dx+ \frac{\alpha}{2}\|u\|^2_{H^1(\Omega)} $, where $y$ is a solution of a partial differential equation. Most of the literature I have encountered primarily deals with control functions in $ L^2(\Omega) $ (that is, with a tracking term like $\frac{\alpha}{2}\|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} $).
I am particularly interested in understanding the second-order optimality conditions for these types of problems. Specifically, I am looking for references or papers where the authors address second-order conditions for controls in $ H^1(\Omega) $.
If anyone knows of any books, articles, or papers that cover this topic, could you please share them?
Thank you very much for your assistance!

Do you have constraints on $u$?

@gerw Yes, I do. Pointwise box constraints in $L^\infty(\Omega}$.

If I understand your comment correctly, you are minimizing over a set
$$
U := \{ u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid a \le u \le b \}
$$
for some $a, b \in L^\infty(\Omega)$.
Such a set is polyhedric in the sense of Mignot. This also allows for nice second-order conditions, see, e.g., Section 3.2.3 in the book "Perturbation analysis of optimization problems" by Bonnans and Shapiro.

Exactly. Thanks for the reference.
